# Read a specific word from text file

Tags: c

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *filePointer ;
    char dataToBeRead[50];

    filePointer = fopen("input.txt", "r") ;
    while( fgets ( dataToBeRead, 50, filePointer ) != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%s" , dataToBeRead ) ;
    }
    fclose(filePointer) ;

}
```

And this is the text file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRnJ7.png). I want to take the word in the middle of each line and print it.

Comment: `50` is pretty tiny as a buffer. Consider a larger buffer size, like `1024` by default.

Comment: If you edit the question to include a description of the problem that you are having with your attempt to do what you describe, The question could be re-opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```c
  strtok(str, ",")
  strtok(NULL, ",")
  printf("%s\n", str);
```

This is not thread-safe or re-entrant but you're unlikely to care about that for this exercise.

If this is too fancy (I assume this is a student exercise and a simpler version may be desired) try stepping through the string character-by-character, counting commas and using `putchar` during the appropriate section.

Answer (score 0):

As with many tasks in C, there are lots of ways to do this one.  One suggestion could be to use the [strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) and [snprintf()](https://tutorialspoint.dev/language/cpp/snprintf-c-library) functions to help find the beginning of the search word then truncate the rest of line to include only the word of interest: (your code modified to use this approach)

```
while( fgets ( dataToBeRead, 50, filePointer ) != NULL )
{
     char *temp = strstr(dataToBeRead, "SearchTerm");
     if(temp != NULL)
     {
         char found[50]={0};
         snprintf(found, strlen("searchTerm"), temp)
         printf( "%s" ,  found) ;
     }
     ...
```

Another way, (simpler, but perhaps not as satisfying) simply *test* the input buffer for existence of the search term using `strstr()` (as the above example does), but if `strstr()` does not return `NULL`, then simply print out the given search term without bothering to parse its twin from out of the line buffer.

Aside:  Magic numbers (Such as `50` in your example: `char dataToBeRead[50];` are not as useful as human readable and understandable variables and/or `#define` values, eg:

```
#define MAX_FILE_LINE_LEN 50
```

Then in your code, everywhere `50` would  be used, replace it with `MAX_FILE_LINE_LEN`
And, while on the topic, use a more reasonable length than 50. At least 80, but 260 would not be too big for most systems either.